# ASP.NET Core 1.0 Global exception handler in console application (DNX)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, dnx, asp.net-core-1.0

I'm trying to handle unhandled exceptions in asp.net 5 console application but I can't seem to catch these errors using the code believe. As soon as the exception is thrown the code breaks. Is there any way in a dnx app to catch unhandled exceptions?

```
public class Program
{
    [STAThread]
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {           
        #if !DNXCORE50


        // Register unhandled exception handler
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(UnhandledExceptionHandler);

        // Throw exception
        throw new Exception("1");

        #endif            
        Console.ReadLine();
    }



    #if !DNXCORE50


    /// <summary>
    ///  Catch all unhandled exceptions in all threads.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="args"></param>
    private static void CurrentDomain_UnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs args)
    {
        try
        {
            // Get the exception that was thrown
            Exception exceptionThrown = (Exception)args.ExceptionObject;

            Console.WriteLine("Information coming from exception handler");                                
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {                
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());                
        }
    }

    #endif

}
```

Comment: It doesn't get called because your exception is thrown in the console app and not the level of your app domain? In other words your exception in the console application is thrown a level higher than where you listen for the UnhandledException event. Does that make sense?

Comment: I think I understand what you mean, so what would I need to do to grab these exceptions?

Comment: @DotnetShadow please consider answer below.

Answer (score 0):

You can output exceptions to the command prompt.

"The dnx command references several environment variables, such as DNX_TRACE, that affect its behavior.

Set the DNX_TRACE environment variable to 1, and run the application again. You should see a great deal more output."

You can read more about it [here](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/dnx/console.html)

Comment: Thanks for the extra information, but I'm trying to catch the error so I can log it. Although your information shows how to get extra information. The .NET team are working on this issue to provide a way of capturing the exception. https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/issues/2999